# How to create Angularjs layout templates

Tags: node.js, angularjs

I am creating a node.js web application where I am using Yeoman angular scaffolding for client side.

I have an index.html which has all the javascript files included to load.

What i want to do is have a header file that will contain users name using model binding. These need to be included in all pages.

How can i achieve this?

Comment: I make the main layout with jade and the partials by angular take a look at mean.io

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use [ng-include](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angInclude) directive to include partials.

Your index page would be structure something like

```
<body>
   <div id='header' ng-include='/partials/header'/>
   <div ng-view />
</body>
```

Comment: Would i need to create factory method which will allow me to change the username when logging in?

Comment: It could be a factory or a global event `$broadcast`ed when user logs in.

Comment: You should create a service such `UserService`, with method such as `getCurrentUser` which would return a user object. This service can be injected into the controller which handles the header html.

Comment: Thanks have you got an example of an injection method?